# Can connect to nginx server inside LAN but not publicly

Tags: linux, http, nginx, raspberry-pi, mastodon

I'm trying to set up a Mastodon instance on my Raspberry Pi 4 at home, running Raspbian/Debian Linux. I have no idea what I'm doing.

The nginx server is running, working. When I access it from localhost or from inside the LAN, it gives a result like this, as expected:

[image]

When I try to access it from outside the LAN, it eventually times out or gives a "connection was reset" error.

[image]

Or in firefox:

[image]

At first I suspected that it was a problem with my firewall, like maybe it was blocking HTTP traffic into it. But it's allowing HTTP traffic through. I even stopped the firewall entirely, but it's still doing the same thing. (I'm using IPTables)

[image]

All of the necessary ports should be forwarded to the pi on my optimum router:

[image]

Here's the site's nginx config, just an edited copy of mastodon's given nginx configuration template. I have the HTTPS server commented out, as I'm only working with HTTP right now. I'm trying to get the http server working so I can use certbot to get an SSL certificate, but certbot's unable to connect to the nginx server, runs into the same "connection reset" error. The server_name is irrelevant (or is it?) as i'm just trying to connect to it through IP right now, and commented out the other "location" properties that the template came with, as I'm just trying to get the server to work in the first place, running mastodon on it and getting the SSL certificate and getting the domain to work will come after.

[image]

What causes it to work inside LAN but not outside it? Even with the necessary ports forwarded to the pi?

Edit:
Here's what it looks like inside the LAN, working correctly:
[image]

and here's when I try to access it outside the LAN (through ProtonVPN in this case)

[image]

Comment: Also, i can connect to the raspi otherwise - i can ssh to it, vnc to it, etc.

Comment: Can you ssh and vnc from outside your LAN?

Comment: Yes, i can @ofirule

Comment: also, no idea if it's relevant at all but it's connected through ethernet

Comment: im so confused i've been at this for days

Comment: Although it's not clear why SSH and VNC would work but not HTTP, I would be wary of your routing configuration.   It's one reason why things can work on your local network but not beyond that (i.e. ARP takes care of it on the LAN).  Checking your routing table setup and tracing on ARP as well as TCP might be helpful.

Comment: If ssh and vnc works outside of LAN I guess it's your router firewall or routing config or something similar

Comment: Is the Nginx log available to you?

Comment: I'd go the same route as @ofirule and suspect your ISP may actively block those ports in an effort to prevent abuse. Can you try some other well-known ports? You an use `nc` to hold arbitrary ports open and check them with `nmap`.

Comment: Optimum should allow these ports through - when i go into the router settings to port forward, it gives a list of services/well known ports, has http/https as options, i don't know why those ports would be shown as presets/options if they were blocked by optimum

Comment: @DaSourcerer I tried configuring the nginx server to listen on ports 8000 or 25565 (just a port that i know optimum doesn't have blocked since i hosted a minecraft server on this router before), trying to access it through <ip>:8000 and <ip>:25565, as well as forwarding port 80 -> 8000 and 80 -> 25565, still the same "connection was reset" error

Comment: also, i'm using https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to check what ports are open, it's saying 22 and 5900 are open but 443 and 80 aren't, interesting

Comment: at this point i have no idea why 21 and 22 and 5900 are open but any other port i try to open aren't

Comment: or does a service have to be running on the pi on a port for the port to show as open? ill check that

Comment: oh yeah i guess something has to be listening on a port for that port to show as open on that site i linked

Comment: made sure again that the IPtables service isn't running, the ports still show as closed

Comment: also i made sure that the NC tool actually works to hold a port, tested on port 21, stopped vsftpd and ran nc on port 21, shown as open, stopped nc, shown as closed. on any other port, ones i made sure was port forwarded, with the IPTables service stopped, the ports won't show as open

Comment: ???? i allowed port 25565 in /etc/iptables/rules.v4, ran nc on port 25565, checked it on that site and it said it was open now? even though before, when i had the iptables service stopped, it said it was closed

Comment: do the firewall rules apply even when the iptables service isn't running?

Comment: also i had ports 80 and 443 allowed in the firewall rules, this whole time, but they were still showing as closed

Comment: ill try choosing a port other than 80 or 443, allow it in my firewall, port forward, test with nc and see if it's open correctly, then try putting the nginx server on that port

Comment: and that works! huh

Comment: but i'd rather not have to connect to the site through example.com:8000, maybe i'll contact optimum support and see if they can do anything about it

Comment: or know anything about it

Comment: actually first i wanna make sure it's not a problem with iptables, im just gonna allow all traffic through and see if i can access port 80

Comment: yep, not a problem with iptables

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/OPTIMUM/comments/rxjw1v/optimum_internet_not_forwarding_traffic_on_port_80/
oh yeah,
this was the problem all along,
just need to contact optimum support

Comment: ok, thank you optimum support, referred me to this obscure page that i cannot find linked anywhere that did what i needed, https://www.optimum.net/internet/boost/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.reddit.com/r/OPTIMUM/comments/rxjw1v/optimum_internet_not_forwarding_traffic_on_port_80/
By default, Optimum blocks ports 80 and 25, even if they are port-forwarded.

Optimum support referred me to this obscure page that I couldn't find linked anywhere on the site, did exactly what i needed: https://www.optimum.net/internet/boost/

Comment: don't know how to remove the bounty

Comment: You can't award it to yourself, I'm afraid. As for removing the bounty, it will simply time out. See ‘[How is a bounty awarded?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)’